# Swift: Apply CGSize to Button Class not changing

Tags: ios, swift, class, uibutton

I am trying to add all style info into a class and then subclass a UIButton to avoid duplication of code.

At the moment, my class looks like:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {


  required init() {

    super.init(frame: .zero)

    // set other operations after super.init, if required
    backgroundColor = .red
    layer.cornerRadius = 5
    layer.borderWidth = 1
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    frame.size = CGSize(width: 700, height: 100)

  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

}
```

In the viewDidLoad I am adding:

```
  let b1 = CustomButton()

  view.addSubview(b1)

  // auto layout
  b1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  b1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
  b1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

As you can see in the class I have set the frame.size

```
 frame.size = CGSize(width: 700, height: 100)
```

However, when I run it, It looks like so:

[image]

The width is clearly not **700**. Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are mixing frame and auto layout. Specifically, once you turn off autoresizing, the frames go away. Why not do 100% auto layout? In fact, why not make centerX/centerY part of the `init()`?

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    required init(width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat, centerButton:Bool) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        // set other operations after super.init, if required
        backgroundColor = .red
        layer.cornerRadius = 5
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        if centerButton {
            self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview?.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            self.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview?.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

And change your call in `viewDidLoad()` to:

```
let b1 = CustomButton(width:700, height:100, centerButton:true)
```

(I added the width/height specs to `init()` to make your code more flexible.)

EDIT: Regards to my last (parenthesized) statement. If all you do is replace:

```
frame.size = CGSize(width: 700, height: 100)
```

with:

```
self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 700).isActive = true
self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

Everything will work. But, in your question you also said that (emphasis mine):

> I am trying to add all style info into a class and then subclass a
>   UIButton to **avoid duplication of code**.

While the code is untested, I added parameters to the `init` in an effort to make the code more adaptable to creating buttons on the fly. Depending on your needs, you can extend this to everything from `backgroundColor` to `cornerRadius`.

I come from an OOP background (actually a top-down back in the 70s), so *subclassing* is way too intuitive to me. What I presented was just that - subclass to avoid duplication of code. Swift presents new ways - specifically `extension` and `convenience init`. I think both of these would even work for you. I'm not sure of the specific pros/cons of extension versus subclassing - my feeling is that duplication of code is about the same (technically) for both - but I'll *always* appreciate what a "modern" language brings to a developer's toolkit!

Comment: Cn you explain the center button Bool and why it's there? I'm eventually going to have 6 buttons on the view controller with different locations. This uibutton were centered for the purpose of this question only. The others will be radom places on the screen

Comment: I have accepted the answer,if I take out all the center stuff it work perfect :)

Comment: Taking this in pieces (and understanding I posted untested code and you probably have more code than posted)... (1) The bottom line issue was mixing frames and constraints, along with turning off auto-resizing. I'll post an edit to my answer to explain more on this. (2) You spoke of - and I agree - avoiding duplication of code. My attempt was to not just *fix* the specific issue, but to add as much as I knew could be into the `init` method. Thus, width/height *and* whether you wanted each button centered, or like you've indicated, not. In fact....

Comment: Taking this to the extreme, you could add *more* parameters to `init`, and when initializing a `CustomButton`, position it completely (along with giving each a specific `backgroundColor`, `cornerRadius`, etc. That sort of thing depends on your specific needs. All told, I was just showing that you could (a) fix the specific issue by using auto layout constraints, (b) move constraints that address the superview into the `init`, and (c) set up the `init` such that your view controller is more "expressive" and has less code.

Answer (score 0):

To decide any views position or size ,you can use either
Frames based layout or constrain based Autolayout  not both together.

Thanks